# My argument for the Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

So, I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $a < b$ and let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $f(a) < 0$ and $f(b) > 0$, then there exists a $c \in (a,b)$ so that $f(c) = 0$.

---

Proof Attempt:

Define the following set:

$$S = \{z \in [a,b]: f(z) < 0 \}$$

Since $a \in S$, $S \neq \varnothing$. Furthermore, $b$ is an upper bound for $S$. Hence, $c = \sup(S)$ exists by the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$. We will prove that $f(c) = 0$.

Let $\delta > 0$ be given. Then, I claim that there has to exist at least one element of $S$ in the interval $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$. Otherwise, all elements of $S$ lie to the left of $c-\delta$ and so, $c-\delta$ is an upper bound of $S$. That is impossible.

Suppose that $f(c) \neq 0$. If $f(c) > 0$, then the continuity of $f$ at $x = c$ tells us that:

$$\exists \delta > 0: |x-c| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)| < f(c)$$

Then, we have:

$$|x-c| < \delta \implies 0 < f(x) < 2f(c)$$

which is a contradiction because we were guaranteed the existence of at least one point of $S$ in the interval $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$ and, hence, at least one point where $f(x) < 0$.

If $f(c) < 0$, then by the continuity of $f$ at $c$, we have:

$$\exists \delta >0: |x-c| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)| < |f(c)|$$

$$|x-c| < \delta \implies f(c) - |f(c)| < f(x) < 0$$

which implies that there is a $z > c$ so that $z \in S$. Hence, $c$ is not an upper bound of $S$ and that is a contradiction. It follows that $f(c) = 0$, as was desired. $\Box$

Does the proof above work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Bump, can anyone check if my argument above works haha? I'm refraining from looking at the proofs because I want to know specifically what is wrong with my own reasoning (if it is wrong).

Comment: You have two small gaps. In your argument, at one point you implicitly use $c > a$, and at another point you implicitly use $c < b$. But you haven't shown that this is the case.

Comment: Well, if c = a, then f(c) < 0 and we get issues arising in a contradiction. If c = b, then f(c) > 0 and that again results in a contradiction. Is that not enough?

Comment: _How_ do you get the contradiction? That ought to be stated, or you could also say at both cases that the assumption rules out one boundary point ($f(c) < 0$ rules out $c = b$, and $f(c) > 0$ rules out $c = a$). These are small things, but at a point where one proves the intermediate value theorem, they should not go unmentioned.

Comment: Well, the contradiction is exactly the fact that if $f(c) > 0$, then $f(x) > 0$ in a $\delta$-neighbourhood of $c$. But this is impossible because we've guranteed the existence of a point of $S$ in every $\delta$-neighbourhood of $c$. In the other case, I did mention the contradiction. Yea, I guess I should've been explicit about the fact that $c \neq a$ and $c \neq b$.

Comment: But the reason you gave for that doesn't work for $c = a$ (of course in that case we have $c \in S$, so the conclusion still holds, but the argument did not cover all cases). [Yes, I'm being pedantic, but that was the point of the question, wasn't it?]

Comment: Pedantry is good and exactly what I want. I just need to check if I'm getting this absolutely right because I feel like i'm there. If $c = a$, then the function is right continuous at $a$ so we can show that there exists an interval $(a,a+\delta)$ in which $f(x) < 0$ for all $x \in (a,a+\delta)$. This would follow from $f(a) < 0$. However, by the definition of $c$, every $b \geq x > a$ gives rise to $f(x) > 0$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, and at the other end, continuity at $b$ gives $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x) > 0$ on $(b - \delta, b]$. The point is that the argument "$f(c) > 0$ implies that $c$ is not the _least_ upper bound" requires $c > a$, and the argument "$f(c) < 0$ implies that $c$ is not an upper bound" requires $c < b$. These are easy, in fact they are immediate from the respective assumptions, but it needs to be mentioned.

Comment: Oh alright, nice. Thank you so much for your help, I'll take note of all of this.